# Using CLT to determine the sample size to achieve a given power.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a distribution having a pmf of the form $f(x;\theta)=\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$ $x=0,1$, zero elsewehre. Let $H_0: \theta=\frac{1}{20}$ and $H_1: \theta>\frac{1}{20}$. Use the Central Limit Theorem to determine the sample size  of a random sample so that a uniformly most powerful test of $H_0$ vs $H_1$ has a power function $\gamma(\theta)$ with approximately $\gamma(\frac{1}{20})=.05$ and $\gamma(\frac{1}{10})=.90$.

For simplicity let $H_{0}:\theta=\frac{{1}}{20}=\theta'$
 and let $H_{1}:\theta>\frac{1}{20}=\theta''$. Then $\frac{{L(\theta')}}{L(\theta'')}=(\frac{{\theta'(1-\theta')}}{\theta''(1-\theta''})^{\sum x_{i}}(\frac{1-\theta'}{1-\theta''})^{n}$
  where $\sum x_{i}\sim Bin(n,\theta)$.

From here I'm not sure how to bring in the CLT and estimate $n$